# Is there any reason to use LastEvaluatedKey in addition to condition expression in DynamoDB queries?

Tags: api, pagination, amazon-dynamodb

I'm implementing pagination for a resource backed by a DynamoDB table.
In the first request I'm passing key condition expression of the form `hashKey = X and sortKey >= Initial_Y`. In the following requests, I will pass similar expressions of the form `hashKey = Y and sortKey > Last_Y`. This approach looks sufficient.

Now, I'm reading DynamoDB docs and some articles about building pagination on DynamoDB. They all only mention `LastEvaluatedKey` without even addressing the issue of its seeming redundancy. Using `LastEvaluatedKey` does not seem to make the solution any simpler than the approach I described above.

So, is there any benefit in using `LastEvaluatedKey` for pagination instead of the key condition expression? Or is it there due to historical reasons?

Answer (score 1):

In the simple format that you explain, it would seem that its not got many benefits. However, when you are using a `Scan` or even a `Query` on a GSI then the LastEvaluatedKey LEK is not just a pointer to the last read item, it can contain multiple values such as PK/SK for base table as well as PK/SK for the index if its an index you're reading from.

Furthermore, you can pass the LEK to the ExclusiveStartKey ESK as is, you do not need to obtain or resolve any values, whereas with your suggested approach you would have to obtain the last sort-key value used and manually pass that value to your `KeyConditionExpression` which can easily lead to user error.

Comment: For Scan it makes total sense (if it works as expected i.e. skipping all items up till LEK without spending a single RCU).

Comment: For Query - I'm not that sure. IIUC, it is not powerful enough to let me change the pagination direction. In most pagination solutions, you typically want [to give your customers] both options: go forward or go backward from the current page.